# Android app maximum RAM usage is high and average RAM usage is low

Tags: android, ram

I'm new to android. I have made an app that displays the data usage of all the apps in a recycler view (according to the date provided by the user).

When I see the RAM usage in Android Studio Profiler, it is showing a maximum of 120 MB.
But, when I open the RAM usage of my app in the physical device, it shows that the maximum RAM usage is around 500 MB, and average RAM usage is around 10 MB.

I used it for around 10 minutes. Is it normal or consuming a lot of RAM?

Android Studio may be showing wrong usage. How to get the correct usage in the profiler?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the device has 4+GB of RAM it could be normal and depends of what kind of data you are showing for each row. If each row has a (quite large) Bitmap it could be normal.... However you can start Profiling your App using relative Tab in Android Studio. Then you can press appropriate button from the Profiler and show which Java Objects are using more memory and fix it if required.